# Verify that the logic !(a==k || b==k || c==k) is not equivalent to (a != k || b!=k || c!=k)

Tags: logic, conditional-statements

I ran into a bug in my program where I had to differentiate between the cases stated in the title. a,b,c are distinct entities but either a,b, or c may equal k.

My intent, which was to be represented as a compound logical statement, was to say that if a,b,or c equals k (a==k or b==k or c==k), then the statement should return false.

The buggy expression was: (a!=k || b!=k || c!=k)
My correction was:  !(a==k || b==k || c==k) 
The reasoning being that the former says that at a,b, AND c needs to equal k for the statement to be false.

I just wanted to verify my correction.

Comment: You should be able to trivially observe that if `a` and `b` are distinct (that is, `a!=b`), `a!=k || b!=k` will always be true.

Comment: The equivalence of logical expressions might be better discussed on http://math.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Possibly although we do make use of it frequently when writing `if` statements.

Comment: @ Damien I see. If it's false, then a==k and b==k but a!=b so it is never true that that statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(a == k || b == k || c == k)` is equivalent to `!(a != k && b != k && c != k)`. This is an application of *De-Morgan's law*.

The formal proof is not easy so will not attempt to give it. (But is one of the first proofs you can do once you've established some mathematical axioms.) You can prove that your statements are not equivalent by using a counterexample: setting `a != b` will mean that `(a != k || b != k || c != k)` is *always* true, but `!(a == k || b == k || c == k)` *might* be true.

Answer (score 0):

Of course their not equivalent. The first one is equivalent to a conjunction of inequalities when you use de-morgan's. An example where they are different: `a=1, k=2, b=2, c=3`.